# Error 1064 - using the IN statement

Tags: mysql

List customer names who ordered Apple Laptop (Choose your own join type). I have gour tables customer, orderline, ordertable, and product. I keep getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''product' where product_name = 'Apple Laptop'))) LIMIT 0, 25' at
>   line 4

```
select customer.cust_name
from customer
where customer.cust_id in (
        select cust_id
        from ordertable
        where order_id in (
                select order_id
                from orderline
                where product in (
                        select product_id
                        from 'product'
                        where product_name = 'Apple Laptop'
                        )
                )
        )
```

Comment: remove the single quotes from `'product'`

Comment: I did that and got the error below

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'product' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: @TaborWarren It's the `where product in` clause. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your schema, this is a bit challenging, but after you removed the quotes from `'product'` the error is saying that there is no column `product` in the outer clause. We can infer that you are selecting `product_id` in the deepest subquery, so the outer where clause likely needs to use `product_id` and not `product`.

```
select customer.cust_name
from customer
where customer.cust_id in (
        select cust_id
        from ordertable
        where order_id in (
                select order_id
                from orderline
                where product_id in ( -- <-- ERROR HERE
                        select product_id
                        from product
                        where product_name = 'Apple Laptop'
                        )
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from 'product' in the last select statement. It's the name of a table, so it does not need to be quoted.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'product' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'